# What is the simplest way to graph rrd files in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, rrdtool, rrd

I have several Python scripts that output metrics to rrd formatted files. Although I have been using rrdtool for graphing, I am wondering if there is any simple way that I can directly graph rrd files in Grafana.

I have found a few possibilities but they seem to require the rrd files to have been generated through Cacti or OpenNMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphite http://graphiteapp.org supports reading data from rrd files, you will want to symlink the folder containing your rrd files to an `rrd` folder in the Graphite storage dir, then you'll be able to query them via Grafana with all the capabilities of the Graphite API.

Answer (score 7):

The Grafana RRD Server perhaps?
https://github.com/doublemarket/grafana-rrd-server

Comment: Any idea how to change the item names in the legend ?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently implemented a grafana plugin for this use case:

https://github.com/andrewchambers/grafana-rrd-datasource